Showing blazor component on button click
I am currently learning blazor and tried to modify the template to show weather on button click
here is the code:
    @page "/"

    <PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => showWeather=!showWeather)">Show weather:</button>

    @if (showWeather)
    {
        <Weather />
    }

    @code {
        bool showWeather { get; set; } = false;
    }

if I put  anywhere else or change it to @if (!showWeather) it works, why is the bool value not changing?
